# Is there a cross-platform GUI framework for C#/.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, cross-platform

Let's say just for the joy of it, I decide that I don't want to write desktop applications in Java any more, instead want to switch to using C#.  I want to be able to build an application that will run on some mainstream Linux distribution, and a recent release of MS Windows.  It will have a GUI component.

In Java I can build an application that uses Swing.  Once I have it working, I can copy that jar file from Windows to Linux or vice versa, depending where I developed it.  And it will generally run with `java -jar myapp.jar`.

In C# is it possible to do this?  Is there a functional equivalent to Swing or AWT in C#?

Answer (score 23):

There's [Eto.Forms](https://github.com/picoe/Eto) (on github), which is an abstraction layer on top of **WPF**, **WinForms**, **GTK**, and **MonoMac/Cocoa** - so you can get a native UI on all platforms without having to re-implement for each platform.  You don't have to suffer from lowest common denominator, since you can implement specifics for each platform (if desired, but not required).

It has an advantage that it is pure .NET and only relies on OS-supplied dependencies, as opposed to using GTK or WxWidgets where you'd have to bundle the native binaries for various platforms.

Comment: Hello! Can I use Eto.Forms with Gtk# on Windows? Thanks!

Comment: @user2656632 yes, you certainly can. Just pass the appropriate platform to the Eto.Forms.Application constructor. (;

Answer (score 14):

Probably [GTK#](http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharp) would be the closest.

I know others have said mono, but that's not quite right.  .Net is to mono as Microsoft's Java VM is to Sun's Java runtime.  mono's not really in the same conceptual space as Swing.  For that, GTK# is a closer match.

Comment: I know what you're saying, in his question he asked about AWT or Swing - but what I think he's really asking is "how can I write cross-platform C# apps?".

Comment: This is very old now. Something based on XAML is a better bet.

Answer (score 6):

[This page](http://mono-project.com/Gui_Toolkits) has a list of the GUI toolkits supported by Mono, including pros and cons for each of them.  As others have suggested, WinForms, GTK#, and wxNet are all viable options.

Answer (score 5):

I believe a good portion of WinForms is implemented in Mono. You need to install Mono under Linux for that. You may have compatibility problems, though, since Mono is not a Microsoft effort and is not officially supported by them.

Comment: Yes, but it is a very *good* community effort, and I've only seen compatibility problems when I was doing something completely ridiculous (comments are too short to describe :D). Normal desktop programming is usually just fine.

Comment: As far as i am aware all of WinForms 2.0 is implemented.

Comment: WinForms really?  That's interesting. When last I checked a few years ago, there was nothing.

Comment: As far as i am aware all of WinForms 2.0 is implemented.

Comment: @Jay: key phrase there is "a few years ago"  mono is still a very active project.

Comment: The only thing missing from the Mono WinForms implementation is support for ActiveX controls when running on platforms other than Windows (for obvious reasons). So long as you don't use such controls, you're fine.

Comment: Using WinForms for a cross platform UI is probably one of the worst things to do.  It only works well on windows - It looks and works horrendously on Linux and OS X, and no one would enjoy using your application on either platform.  Using a UI abstraction like Eto.Forms (see my answer) to get native UI, or even using GTK are better options.

Comment: @Curtis, this is a 4-year old answer, and at the time, it was not an awful thing to do. Today, there are potentially better options, but keep the time of the question/answer in mind.

Comment: @unforgiven3, I understand this is an old answer though I am trying to help future programmers that come to this answer for a solution. I will remove the downvote as it doesn't seem proper etiquette - Sorry for the trouble. edit: seems I can't remove it anymore.

Answer (score 5):

There are plenty these days. It depends on what you are looking for. [Here](https://christianfindlay.com/2019/05/11/cross-platform-c-ui-technologies/) is a detailed write-up about these three choice technologies. They are not the only technologies, but they have the most buzz around them right now.

[Xamarin Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/)

C#, XAML Based, Microsoft owned Open Source, Supports Android, iOS, UWP, and more. Native rendering.

[Uno Platform](https://platform.uno/)

C#, XAML Based, Open Source, Supports Android, iOS, UWP, and more. Native rendering.

[Avalonia](http://avaloniaui.net/)

C#, XAML Based, Open Source, Supports Linux, MacOS, Windows, and more. Pixel perfect rendering on each platform.

Comment: Breaking News: as of April 2022, you can also start playing with Microsoft's next multi-platform GUI SDK (also free and open source), known as [.NET MAUI](https://github.com/dotnet/maui). It's the next evolutionary step for those coming from Xamarin. It should be interesting to see what the 'competition' will be launching to counter Microsoft.

Comment: @GwynethLlewelyn 'Competition' Google has already launched Flutter which is already stable for all underlying platforms. Hope that .NET MAUI doesn't turn out like another shit UI framework from MS.

Comment: @demberto you're right — the OP should add https://developers.google.com/learn/topics/flutter to the official links of 'technologies with most buzz these days'. I've never used Flutter, but it seems at least to preserve so-called 'native' UI elements instead of overriding everything as some toolkits do.

Comment: @GwynethLlewelyn Native UI is a big pile of crap these days. Every goddamn company is trying to steal the look and feel from each other. Custom UI gives an app a professional look and a unique brand if done well

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft just recently launched [.NET MAUI](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-multi-platform-app-ui/), which builds on Xamarian and supports .NET core.

In their words:

> As we consider what building device applications will look like in a unified .NET, we see many devices across multiple platforms used, from Android and iOS to Windows and macOS. To address this need we are excited to announce a new first-class UI framework for doing just that: .NET Multi-platform App UI, affectionately call .NET MAUI.
>
> .NET MAUI simplifies the choices for .NET developers, providing a single stack that supports all modern workloads: Android, iOS, macOS, and Windows.

Although they do not specify Linux, according to the [MAUI Github Repo](https://github.com/dotnet/maui) there is community developed support for it.

Comment: It would be more accurate to say that Microsoft recently "announced" .NET MAUI, rather than "launched". It is not scheduled for general release until November 2021: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Roadmap

Answer (score 4):

This is an older question, but as an update, a combination of Mono and Xamarin should work for your modern cross-platform needs.

http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/

Microsoft has just open-sourced .NET and is committing to bringing the .NET core to Linux and MacOS with their next version. Microsoft has also formed a close partnership with Mono and Xamarin, specifically to help with their Android and Linux libraries.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AnnouncingNET2015NETAsOpenSourceNETOnMacAndLinuxAndVisualStudioCommunity.aspx

Comment: And in 2022 the .NET core works natively _and_ Roslyn compiles at a mind-dazzling speed under whatever operating system you prefer, as well as on any CPU out there. Well, almost. Let's say that 99.9% of the systems are supported. **Natively**. No emulation, no Mono subsystem, no Wine, nothing. You get CLI apps that look and feel exactly the same as any other Unix apps compiled with, say, GCC. Alas — no GUI (yet), we'll have to use [.NET MAUI](https://github.com/dotnet/maui) instead (which was just released). Or any other alternative mentioned on the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [WxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/). It has support for C#, among many other languages, and is cross-platform. The only downside being a recompile for each platform. Alternatively you can try Mono which is very good, but beware there are a couple snags with compatibility issues. There is no predefined "run anywhere" file for C# apps yet like Java has with jars though, you're best bet is to recompile for each platform if you want to ensure compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing I've ever seen is Mono - though it doesn't support all the CLR libraries yet I believe, but it is cross-platform.

Answer (score 2):

For iOS, Android, and Windows Mobile, there is Xamarin.Forms.  http://xamarin.com/forms  This is an abstraction layer that allows you to write cross-platform code, which binds to the native GUI toolkits under the hood.

I am looking for more solutions like this - I care not only about mobile platforms, but also desktop platforms (windows, mac OSX, fedora/ubuntu/etc linux)

Answer (score 0):

Windows.Forms is the standard library for developing GUI applications for .NET

Despite of being very well supported on Windows, version 2.0 is fully implemented by Mono too, which makes it available on all platforms supported by Mono.

WPF on the other hand is is conceptually new library, for now it is fully supported mainly on Windows only and just a subset of it supported by Mono by their Silverlight implementation - Moonlight.

If you are building application for productive cross-platform use and/or have conservative performance constraints go Windows Forms.

If you want to experiment and learn something new or if you are developing new application for Windows go WPF. This is the new technology for client GUI applications.

Comment: Mono cannot run Windows.Forms on Linus or Mac since Windows.Forms depends on Win32 API calls.

Comment: Also, at the time of writing, [Microsoft has announced end-of-life support of Silverlight](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/silverlight-end-of-support-0a3be3c7-bead-e203-2dfd-74f0a64f1788). It's time to move on!