# C# Cross platform GUI for desktop and mobile

Tags: c#, user-interface, cross-platform

I have a hobby project that I wrote in C#. Library is for geomatics calculations, it has over 4000 lines of code and I have spent years developing it. Recently I completed GUI using Windows Forms and shared it for free. I got good feedback and now I want to make it cross platform.

Problem is that after days of searching the Internet I found nothing. All links are outdated. I would prefer something like JavaFX, where I could possibly create one GUI for desktop and mobile without much hassle with compiling.

- GTK# is stuck (no mobile and no integration for newer versions with Xamarin studio)
- QtSharp is in Alpha stage
- Eto.Forms for mobile is still under development

Are there any free working alternatives with good tutorials/documentation in late 2016? Or do I have to rewrite my libraries in Java and create GUI in JavaFX?

Comment: What about [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/)? Anyway, this question is offtopic in StackOverflow

Comment: Xamarin is only good for mobile. It seems to me that they abandoned desktop (GTK 2 is too old technology now)

Comment: You question is "GUI for desktop and mobile". If you meant for linux, you can use [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) to run .Net applications in linux

Comment: So I need to create mobile GUI using Xamarin.Forms, and desktop GUI using outdated GTK2? It's not good enough solution. In that case I have to basically maintain 2 applications, where one is using outdated technology.

Comment: You just maintain two GUI components, not two "applications" as lots of non-visual code is still shared. That has already been the golden rule in this space and nobody should expect a one-for-all framework to suddenly come.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a cross-platform GUI framework for C#/.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779283/is-there-a-cross-platform-gui-framework-for-c-net)

Answer (score 2):

At the moment there isn't a .Net framework that support all platform. The solution that covers most platform is [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/) (right now support Android, iOS and MS Universal App). As [this post suggest](https://www.reddit.com/r/programmerchat/comments/4dxpcp/i_am_miguel_de_icaza_i_started_xamarin_mono_gnome/d1vdfwz/?st=iv10qmh6&sh=a36f1de4) probably in the near future there will a Xamarin version also for Linux systems.
But there is an alternative: [duocode](http://duoco.de/). Basically it's a tool that convert c# code into javascript and once is transformed you can use the javascript code to implement a mobile interface using a cross platform framework like cordova. You will have two different application but with the same code base.